# Compare Present Date in two different tables and fetch data in Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables `'Customer_details'` and `'Application_Status'` both tables have the date, a `where-in` `customer_details` table has

Signup `Date[Format: DD/MM/YYYY (04/12/2018 10:30:00 AM)]`

and `Application_Status` has

Application `Date[Format: YYYY-MM-DD (2018-12-04 04:00:00 PM)]`.

I want to compare both dates with Present Date and fetch both table data.

Comment: Is there any relation between these two tables?

Comment: Yes, the Customer ID `c_id` is common in both tables.

Comment: Are those columns defined as DATETIME or are you really storing dates in a  column defined as varchar or similiar?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is defined as VARCHAR type.

Comment: All dates you store on a database should be defined as DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. If you want to present dates in locale formats you should do this in the presentation layer. When dates are stored as char you have to do all sorts of complicated and error prone fiddling to make them act like simple DATE of DATETIME which MySQL understands and can easily do camparisons on

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
SELECT *
      FROM Customer_details AS cdel
      INNER JOIN Application_Status AS asts
      ON cdel.c_id  = asts.c_id
      WHERE cdel.date = CURDATE() AND asts.date = CURDATE();
```

Or you can use `NOW()` function as:

```
SELECT *
          FROM Customer_details AS cdel
          INNER JOIN Application_Status AS asts
          ON cdel.c_id  = asts.c_id
          WHERE cdel.date = NOW() AND asts.date = NOW();
```

**Note:**

```
SELECT NOW();     -- You will get 2010-12-09 17:10:18
SELECT CURDATE(); -- You will get 2010-12-09
```

[reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: Thank you, but no luck because of DATE format this one is not working.